# Kernel config for keyboard special LEDs

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel

I'm building a 4.9 linux kernel (which is working great) for my T460s. The <kbd>F1</kbd> key has a led that shows if sound is muted. I can't get this LED to work even when enabling all kinds of LED-relevant config options.

- Q1: Am I wrong in assuming that I need to configure LED-related parameters of the kernel?
- Q2: May this rather be related to ACPI?

**Edit**

The backports 4.7 distribution kernel uses the relevant LEDs (F1=mute, F4=mic on/off) just fine. The thing is that I can't spot the relevant configuration option(s), even in a diff...

Comment: This is a very hardware specific question that implies specific drivers that probably don't exist at the moment.  That said, the question is very relevant and I can hopefully be wrong in my assumption.

Comment: Added information on 4.7 backports kernel working fine...

Comment: Do you have both kernel configuration files?

Comment: Yes, but I thought posting 15K lines of config files would not be a good idea. As mentioned, I diffed them and included all `CONFIG_LEDS*` but it seems that this was not the solution.

Comment: You need to establish the list of differences between the two.  Maybe there are other settings that need to be enabled for it to work.  Did you enable GPIO support?

Comment: Yep, all kinds of GPIO-Stuff enabled. Will keep trying.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? My suggestion would be to look at what modules are enabled in the kernel that does work with `lsmod`, then disable them one-by-one with modprobe and see if any of that turns off the LEDs. If none of those do, then they must be controlled by a built-in module.

Comment: No, I didn't get this figured out, but I don't bother as the keys work properly. Only the LEDs do not.